# Lower bound for the number of subsets of connected vertices of a given size, given the number of vertices and edges of an arbitrary graph

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory

After getting the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4544109/573047) another one arose:

For all simple graphs on $n$ vertices with $m$ edges, is it possible to get a lower bound for the number $s$ of subsets of its vertices of a given size $k \le n$ such that there exist at least one connected subgraph on that subset of vertices?

Just as an example of the general problem, if $k=3$ and we replace "connected" with "complete" above (a particular case) we get a lower bound of $\frac{m}{3n}(4m - n^2)$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2654408/573047)).

Comment: Very nice problem. It would already be nice to see what happens for $k = 3$. Obviously the lower bound for the triangle problem is also a lower bound here, but the question if we can get a better bound, i.e. one yielding bigger numbers for the current problem than for the triangle problem, is already not clear.

Comment: Come to think of it, whenever $m$ is a triangular number (nice coincidence that name) it is possible to draw up a graph in which there are no 3-element subsets whose induced subgraph is connected but not a triangle. Hence either the better bound here would be equal to the triangle bound, or it would be an better bound for the triangle problem as well in that case. Do you know if the bound you gave for the triangle problem is sharp?